# How to use Twit package client side

Tags: javascript, html, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using the Twit package to search for tweets. When I run the js file in the console, the tweets appear but I cannot use them on my webpage as it gives me an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'. This is because require isn't defined on the client side.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Your client side browser does not recognize require.  You have quite a few options.  Please see this earlier post to make your choice:

**[Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)**

Comment: I have installed Browserify but it seems as if none of my API queries are successful now. @elimcjah

Comment: That answer does not include SystemJS/JSPM

Comment: @Gordon, Please kindly accept this answer as the answer and throw an up vote if you feel I deserve.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, SystemJS and JSPM are both mentioned in the comments of the accepted answer.